# Why my context (popup) menu in WinAPI doesn't appear?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to setup a context menu using WinAPI in my application, but for some reason I'm not successful. The code that would pop up the menu is placed in the WM_RBUTTONUP case. However, nothing happens after right-click. Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Growing_children_PAWEL_MICHNA.h"

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
//TCHAR szChild1Title[MAX_LOADSTRING];
//TCHAR szChild2Title[MAX_LOADSTRING];
TCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name
TCHAR szChild1WindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];
TCHAR szChild2WindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];

HWND hWnd, child1hWnd, child2hWnd;
HMENU hMenu = LoadMenu(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_CONTEXT_MENU));

int mywidth = 25;
int myheight = 25;
bool greater = true;
// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
ATOM                Child1RegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
ATOM                Child2RegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);

BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    MSG msg;
    HACCEL hAccelTable;

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, NULL, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadString(hInstance, IDC_GROWING_CHILDREN_PAWEL_MICHNA, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadString(hInstance, IDC_CHILD1, szChild1WindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadString(hInstance, IDC_CHILD2, szChild2WindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);
    Child1RegisterClass(hInstance);
    Child2RegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_GROWING_CHILDREN_PAWEL_MICHNA));

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}

ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    HBRUSH redBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 0));
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = NULL; //CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_GROWING_CHILDREN_PAWEL_MICHNA));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = redBrush;
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCE(NULL);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}

ATOM Child1RegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    HBRUSH blueBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 255));
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_PARENTDC; //CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_GROWING_CHILDREN_PAWEL_MICHNA));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = blueBrush;
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCE(NULL);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szChild1WindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}

ATOM Child2RegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    HBRUSH greenBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 255, 0));
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_PARENTDC; //CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_GROWING_CHILDREN_PAWEL_MICHNA));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = greenBrush;
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCE(NULL);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szChild2WindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_LAYERED, szWindowClass, NULL, WS_POPUPWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 500, 500, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   // Set windows transparency to 70%
   SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, 0, (255 * 70) / 100, LWA_ALPHA);

   RECT rc; 

   // get the center of the work area of the system 
   SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA, 0, &rc, 0); 
   int centerX = (rc.left + rc.right + 1) / 2; 
   int centerY = (rc.top + rc.bottom + 1) / 2; 

   //move the main windows to the center
   MoveWindow(hWnd, centerX-250, centerY-250, 500, 500, true);

   child1hWnd = CreateWindow(szChild1WindowClass, NULL, WS_CHILD, 0, 0, 25, 25, hWnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
   SetLayeredWindowAttributes(child1hWnd, 0, (255 * 70) / 100, LWA_ALPHA);

   child2hWnd = CreateWindow(szChild2WindowClass, NULL, WS_CHILD, 475, 476, 25, 25, hWnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
   SetLayeredWindowAttributes(child2hWnd, 0, (255 * 70) / 100, LWA_ALPHA);

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   ShowWindow(child1hWnd, nCmdShow);
   ShowWindow(child2hWnd, nCmdShow);

   UpdateWindow(hWnd);
   UpdateWindow(child1hWnd);
   UpdateWindow(child2hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    POINT point;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        SetTimer(hWnd, 1, 100, NULL);
        return 0; 
    }
        break;
    case WM_RBUTTONUP: 
    {
        point.x = LOWORD(lParam); 
        point.y = HIWORD(lParam); 

        ClientToScreen(hWnd, &point); 
        TrackPopupMenu(hMenu, TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, point.x, point.y, 0, hWnd, NULL); 
        return 0;
    }
    case WM_TIMER:
        if(mywidth < 250 && greater == true)
        {
            MoveWindow(child1hWnd, 0, 0, ++mywidth, ++myheight, true);
            MoveWindow(child2hWnd, 500-mywidth, 500-myheight, mywidth, myheight, true);
            if(mywidth == 250)
                greater = false;
        }
        else
        {
            MoveWindow(child1hWnd, 0, 0, --mywidth, --myheight, true);
            MoveWindow(child2hWnd, 500-mywidth, 500-myheight, mywidth, myheight, true);
            if(mywidth == 0)
                greater = true;
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    case WM_NCHITTEST:
        if (hWnd == child1hWnd || hWnd == child2hWnd) return HTTRANSPARENT;
        return HTCAPTION; 
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

.rc fragment:

```
IDR_CONTEXT_MENU MENU
BEGIN
    MENUITEM "Color",                       ID_COLOR32778
    POPUP "Figures"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "None",                        ID_FIGURES_NONE, CHECKED
        MENUITEM "Square",                      ID_FIGURES_SQUARE
        MENUITEM "Triangle",                    ID_FIGURES_TRIANGLE
        MENUITEM "Circle",                      ID_FIGURES_CIRCLE
    END
    MENUITEM "Exit",                        ID_EXIT
END
```

Comment: As a FYI - you should handle [WM_CONTEXTMENU](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647592(v=vs.85).aspx) rather than WM_RBUTTONUP: that will get fired on both right-click and also on the context menu key, ensuring that your app is keyboard accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `hMenu` is a static variable, which is loaded before `hInst` has a value. I believe the `LoadMenu` call is failing.

You'll also note in the [TrackPopupMenu documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648002%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that not just any menu handle can be used, it has to be a popup menu handle. In the resources, create a single element for the top-level menu and put your popup menu underneath it; then use LoadMenu to load the top-level, and GetSubMenu to get the handle to your drop-down.

Comment: In global variables, at the begining , I left just `HMENU hMenu;`. In the `Init Instance` I put `LoadMenu(hInst, AKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_CONTEXT_MENU));` after `hInst = hInstance;`. However, still no effect.

Comment: Before your call to TrackPopupMenu, call GetCusrorPos instead of ClientToScreen.  Since GetCursorPos will return the position of the cursor for your popup.  ClientToScreen just converts some coords, the popup is probably showing somewhere off screen.

Comment: I modified the code that there is `GetCursorPos(&point);
  TrackPopupMenu(hMenu, TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, point.x, point.y, 0, hWnd, NULL); `, but it hasn't helped.

Comment: @Mark Ransom Yeah, that was the problem. Actually, I found out the solution before your edit but still, thanks!